# getting error response in jmeter while testing google site

Tags: jmeter

while during load testing for one site through j meter getting below

> error:Response code: Non HTTP response code:
>   org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException Response message: Non
>   HTTP response message: Connect to 172.17.4.213:80 timed out

Comment: any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted so it's usable by others

Answer (score 0):

You most probably didn't configure the proxy for JMeter as per:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

Look at your browser (where request works)  proxy configuration for the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your URL/ip address is pointing to your code properly by some online ping tool. And If it is working, check if your network is not blocking site access.